# Residual as percentage of fitted value in R

Tags: r, lm

I'm doing a basic lm model in R. I'd like to get the maximum and average residual *as a percentage* of fitted value, but don't know how to go about this.

So for instance, if I have a dataset of 3 points - my predictions: (2, 8, 9) and I'm fitting them against the actual data: (4, 10, 12), then the maximum residual (observed - predicted) in terms of percentage of fitted value is from the first match-up, as it's 100% of the fitted value (the residual, 4-2 = 2, and the fitted value ie. my prediction was 2). The average residual percentage in this case would be (100 + 25 + 33)/3 = 52% (approx).

Is there a function that will produce these results if given the lm model object, or does anyone have any suggestions for how to code for it? I'm quite new in R, and am not sure how to extract the correct data to do so manually.

Thanks a lot to anyone who helps!

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example.

Comment: Your `lm` call will return the fitted values and residuals to you. You can then calculate your percentages for all and take the maximum from that. Suggest looking at `?lm` for how to access the data you need, hint: `my.model$fitted` and `my.model$resid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter = 1

Percentages = numeric()

Fitted = c(2, 8, 9)

Residuals = c(2, 2, 3)

for (element in Fitted)
    {Current_resid = Residuals[Counter]
    Current_percent = abs((Current_resid/element)*100)
    Percentages = c(Percentages, Current_percent)
    Counter = Counter + 1}
Current_resid
Counter
Percentages
sum_Percent = sum(Percentages)
Average_Percent = sum_Percent/(counter-1)

Counter = 1